# Convert text to date sql

Tags: sql-server, excel, date-conversion

I've seen a few posts on here and dotted around on the internet but I'm still struggling to implement my findings to get this to work.

I am currently trying to pull through a date field and run parameters on this field however everything I do fails and it still comes through as text or I experience an error.

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT CEL_SLT.ACCOUNT, 
       CEL_SLA.NAME, 
       CEL_SLT.STOCK_CODE, 
       **CEL_SLT.DATE**, 
       CEL_SLT.STOCK_QTY, 
       CEL_SLT.AMOUNT, 
       CEL_SLT.ORDER_NO
FROM Datafile.dbo.CEL_SLA CEL_SLA, Datafile.dbo.CEL_SLT CEL_SLT
WHERE CEL_SLA.ACCOUNT = CEL_SLT.ACCOUNT 
AND ((CEL_SLT.STOCK_CODE Like 'F%' And CEL_SLT.STOCK_CODE Not Like 'FNX%')    
AND (CEL_SLT.ACCOUNT=?)
```

I need the field CEL_SLT.DATE to come through as a date field.

I hope this makes sense and someone can help.

Comment: What have you tried, and why didn't that work? `CEL_SLT.DATE` is a (n)varchar I assume? Can you share some sample data?

Comment: What is the question and what is the problem? Excel has no problem reading dates from SQL Server. If you store dates as *strings* though, you have a bug in the database. You should use the *correct* type for each kind of data, eg `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2` etc

Comment: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). However, you would be far better off amending the data type of your table and storing your data as what it is, a `date`. **Always** use an appropriate datatype for your data. `(n)varchar` is not a one size fits all datatype.

Comment: I am guessing the CEL_SLT.DATE column is not a date or datetime datatype ? If so then there is your answer. Fix your table and store your data in the correct datatype. Otherwise you will only find more and more problems as you move further in your development

Comment: I've tried adding "CAST" & "CONVERT" but both return the following error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. I'm unable to amend the data type as it is taken direct from a programme we use called Datafile.

Comment: here is a  good reading https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/

Comment: and another good read http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is clean (in other words, the text data actually looks like a date), you can do it with either the [CAST or CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command.

```
SELECT CAST(CEL_slt.DATE as date)
```

Comment: `Looks like a date` can be different in other regional settings. What looks like a valid date on your system can look like an invalid date on mine

Comment: I've tried both cast and convert with no luck, it does look like a date when it comes through and I can point another cell to look at the data being pulled through with the formula DATEVALUE() and that converts it but I want to run parameters on the data as it pulls through.

Comment: it might look like a date to you, but not to your sql server. There are different date formats if you want to convert from varchar to date. Find out which one you are using and pass that to the cast/convert function. If different formats can exist then forget about this then it will never work

Comment: That’s a different problem. Let’s start with the basics. The original question asked how do I make this value in excel return a date. Cast and Conference are the methods by which. Now if your data looks funny after that, and you need to dive into why. Dates are not easy, but you have to start somewhere.